# Replace missing value in an array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array `A=[3 4 1 2 5 6]` and another array `B=[3 4 0 2 0 0]`

I tried to find out the missing elements of B using `setdiff` function of Matlab.

```
missing_values=setdiff(A,B);
```

i got answer as

```
missing_values= 1 5 6
```

Now i want to replace zeros of array B with missing values....
can you help me?

i tried the code given below:

```
j=1;
missingvalues=setdiff(A,B)
idx= nwP4(2,: )== 0;
if(A(idx)==0)    
A(idx) = missingvalues(j);
j=j+1;    `enter code here`
end
```

but it didn't work.

can you help me?

Comment: I got answer using the code:

j=1;
missingvalues=setdiff(A,B)
idx= nwP4(2,: )== 0;
if(A(idx)==0)    
A(idx) = missingvalues(j);
j=j+1;   
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I assume this is what you are trying to do.

```
A=[3 4 1 2 5 6]
B=[3 4 0 2 0 0]

missing_values=setdiff(A,B);
B(find(~B))=missing_values
```

Or to do it in one line,

```
B(find(~B))=setdiff(A,B);
```

This will leave B with

```
B = [3   4   1   2   5   6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
B(B==0) = missing_values;
```

Or simply put them into one line:

```
B(B==0) = setdiff(A, B);
```

---

**Edit:** Just curious, maybe the example is over-simplified, it seems you eventually want `B` equal to `A`. If so, you can simply do:

```
B = A;
```

Comment: @chappjc Based on the description, it should fit OP's goal. :P

Comment: It sure does. I wonder what the goal really was? Perhaps the example was over-simplified. [shrug]